# Grouping rows after "super row"

Tags: sql, oracle, grouping

I have this table:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| supplier_id | supplier_aggregate_id | supplier_description |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| &&%%        | null                  | UNDEFINED            |
| ...         | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
| +           | null                  | UNDEFINED            |
| ,           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
| .           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

I would like to make a select to have the results this way:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| supplier_id | supplier_aggregate_id | supplier_description |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| &&%%        | null                  | UNDEFINED            |
| ,           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
| .           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
| ...         | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |
| +           | null                  | UNDEFINED            |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

i.e.: a row with a `supplier_id`, followed by all the rows that have `supplier_aggregate_id` equal to the `supplier_id` of the first row.

I tried with ordering:

```
SELECT supplier_id, supplier_aggregate_id, supplier_description
FROM suppliers
ORDER BY supplier_id ASC, supplier_aggregate_id ASC;
```

But i get the `+` record after the first `&&%%` record, which is not correct:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| supplier_id | supplier_aggregate_id | supplier_description |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
| &&%%        | null                  | UNDEFINED            |
| +           | null                  | UNDEFINED            | <-- this should be here
| ,           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |                      |
| .           | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |                      |
| ...         | &&%%                  | UNDEFINED            |                      |
+-------------+-----------------------+----------------------+ <--------------------+
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single query?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67cae/1)

Comment: For SQL stuff, its better to create a sample in the SQLFiddle and post the link here. That way, someone can try there and help you. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1)

Comment: @KevinRave The SQLFiddle is there since I posted the question, look at the very bottom :)

Comment: Yes, I see it. You got the answer, with fiddle!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing that seams to work is this:

```
select 
  s.supplier_id, 
  s.supplier_aggregate_id, 
  s.supplier_description 
from suppliers s
order by 
  COALESCE(s.supplier_aggregate_id, s.supplier_id) asc, 
  s.supplier_aggregate_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67cae/21

Comment: Wow! It seems to work perfectly! I didn't know about the COLAESCE function! Can you add a little explaination of what it does?

Comment: then, is there a way to order the result by supplier_id too without losing the grouping?

Comment: which field is your grouping based on?

Comment: It's based on the `supplier_aggregate_id`. I would like to have all the result sorted by `supplier_id`. Every `supplier_id` should be followed by the corresponding group of `supplier_aggregate_ids` record (sorted by `supplier_aggregate_id` ascending). Is it possible to have something like that?

Comment: Not sure, cause your example has results sorted as my solution does. I think I will need to see more sample data to understand.

Comment: Se the new [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/976ea1/1). I would like to have this data sorted like this: [LINK](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MMUdr.png). As you can see, the "super rows" (the ones with `supplier_aggregate_id=null`, with green background) are sorted, and also their subsets (the blue and orange ones) are sorted. I would like to have a resultset like this. Is this possible?

Comment: (I just noticed, the image is wrong. The last two rows should be inverted)